# How to access meta OpenGraph with Sails Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, facebook, sails.js

I build a website using **Sails js** and **Angularjs** and I want to create facebook share button but I found a problem, it seems they cannot read my meta:og in my layout.ejs file. I am using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ but the result is :

```
Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
```

Here is my code

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Open Graph META Tags"/> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://davidwalsh.name/wp-content/themes/klass/img/facebooklogo.png"/> 
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="David Walsh Blog"/> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Facebook's Open Graph protocol allows for web developers to turn their we">
    <meta name="description" content="{{meta.metaDescription()}}">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{meta.metaKeywords()}}">
    <meta name="author" content="BLAH inc">
    <meta name='subject' content='my subject'>
    <meta name='copyright' content='BLAH inc'>
    <meta name='language' content='ID-id'>
    <meta name='robots' content='index,follow'>
    <meta name='revised' content='Wednesday, 09-Aug-2017, 14:21'>
    <meta name='abstract' content='my abstract'>
    <meta name='topic' content='my topic'>
    <meta name='summary' content='my summary'>
    <meta name='Classification' content='Business'>
    <meta name='owner' content='my owner'>
    <meta name='url' content='https://www.mywebsite.com'>
    <meta name='identifier-URL' content='https://www.mywebsite.com'>
    <meta name='directory' content='submission'>
    <meta name='pagename' content='blah'>
    <meta name='category' content='blah'>
    <meta name='coverage' content='..'>
    <meta name='distribution' content='..'>
    <meta name='rating' content='..'>
    <meta name='revisit-after' content='1 days'>
    <meta name='subtitle' content='..'>
    <meta name='target' content='all'>
    <meta name='HandheldFriendly' content='True'>
    <meta name='MobileOptimized' content='320'>
    <meta name='date' content='Aug. 22, 2016'>
    <meta name='search_date' content='2017-05-09'>
    <meta name='DC.title' content='...'>
```

What is my mistakes?

Comment: What is the URL to the page?

Comment: @WizKid  the URL staging-new.brambang.com:1337

Comment: You have `og:url` set to `https://www.brambang.com/`, so the scraper will try to fetch the meta data from _that_ URL.